# What is the difference between getContentSize() and getBoundingBox()

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

have noticed that the result of

```
1- sprite->getContentSize()
```

and

```
2- sprite->getBoundingBox().size()
```

are different when scaling is involved usually the content size is smaller in value than the bounding box. I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me what the difference is between the two.

Here is what I observed. In case i do not scale my sprite I get the same results from `sprite->getContentSize()` and `sprite->getBoundingBox().size()` . However if I scale my sprite in the following way

```
s->setScaleX((screenSize.width / s->getContentSize().width) * 1); //where screenSize is the Visible size
```

then the bounding box size is greater than the content size. Why is that ?

Comment: I'm not an expert in [tag:cocos2d-x], but I'd suspect the difference is the margin defined for the content appearing.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs :

```
getContentSize () const
Returns the untransformed size of the node.

getBoundingBox () const
Returns an AABB (axis-aligned bounding-box) in its parent's coordinate system.
```

In the image below, the red area is the `contentSize` and the white area is the `boundingBox`. If the red rectangle was not rotated this would be the same.

[image: simpleexample]

Comment: What do you mean by ` the red area is the contentSize` ?